Oracle WebLogic config.cmd is running but it closes as soon as it runs. I can't set up a domain
In Oracle WebLogic 12C installation, cmd and wizard close when it comes to domain installation.
When I run it as an administrator via config.cmd, the wizard seems to open and then it closes directly. I cannot install it.
Windows PowerShell
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> java -version
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $env:JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $env:Path
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files \Go\cmd;D:\apache-maven-3.9.6\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin;D:\apache-maven-3.9.6\bin;C:\Users \USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2\bin;C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.3.2\bin;

As you can see, java also appears to be properly defined.
What should I do?
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\config.cmd 

When I write this, it seems to work, the wizard title opens, but it doesn't work.
I encounter the same problem when I run other cmd files in Oracle.
THE ERROR I FOUND IN THE LOGS
-> ERROR: found unresolved prerequisite DEP for Core Application Server 12.2.1.4.0 (wls_nativeLib - 12.2.1.4.0)[UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED]
PROCESSING PREREQUISITE <DEP for Core Application Server 12.2.1.4.0 (wls_devServer - 12.2.1.4.0)[UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED] [null]> which is required by <Core Application Server 12.2.1.4.0[TINFO|NOTINSTALLED|SELECTED] [null]>
-> ERROR: found unresolved prerequisite DEP for Core Application Server 12.2.1.4.0 (wls_devServer - 12.2.1.4.0)[UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED]
ERROR: couldn't select Core Application Server 12.2.1.4.0[TINFO|NOTINSTALLED|SELECTED] [null]
-> ERROR: found unresolved prerequisite DEP for Toplink 12.2.1.4.0 (toplink_thirdparty - 12.2.1.4.0)[UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED]
PROCESSING PREREQUISITE <DEP for Toplink 12.2.1.4.0 (wls_thirdparty_javaxjson - 12.2.1.4.0)[UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED] [null]> which is required by <Toplink 12.2.1.4.0[TINFO|NOTINSTALLED|SELECTED] [null]>
-> ERROR: found unresolved prerequisite DEP for Toplink 12.2.1.4.0 (wls_thirdparty_javaxjson - 12.2.1.4.0)[UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED]
ERROR: couldn't select Toplink 12.2.1.4.0[TINFO|NOTINSTALLED|SELECTED] [null]
ct Files 12.2.1.4.0[TINFO|NOTINSTALLED|SELECTED] [null]>
-> ERROR: found unresolved prerequisite DEP for Coherence Product Files 12.2.1.4.0 (coherence_discovery - 12.2.1.4.0)[UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED]
PROCESSING PREREQUISITE <DEP for Coherence Product Files 12.2.1.4.0 (toplink_coherence - 12.2.1.4.0)[UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED] [null]> which is required by <Coherence Product Files 12.2.1.4.0[TINFO|NOTINSTALLED|SELECTED] [null]>
-> ERROR: found unresolved prerequisite DEP for Coherence Product Files 12.2.1.4.0 (toplink_coherence - 12.2.1.4.0)[UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED]
PROCESSING PREREQUISITE <Toplink 12.2.1.4.0[TINFO|NOTINSTALLED|SELECT
-> ERROR: found unresolved prerequisite DEP for CIE WLS Config 12.2.1.4.0 (cieCfg_wls_external - 12.2.1.4.0)[UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED]
PROCESSING PREREQUISITE <DEP for CIE WLS Config 12.2.1.4.0 (cieCfg_wls_shared - 12.2.1.4.0)[UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED] [null]> which is required by <CIE WLS Config 12.2.1.4.0[TINFO|NOTINSTALLED|SELECTED] [null]>
-> ERROR: found unresolved prerequisite DEP for CIE WLS Config 12.2.1.4.0 (cieCfg_wls_shared - 12.2.1.4.0)[UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED]
ERROR: couldn't select CIE WLS Config 12.2.1.4.0[TINFO|NOTINSTALLED|SELECTED] [null]
-> ERROR: found unresolved prerequisite DEP for Administration Console Additional Language Help Files 12.2.1.4.0 (wls_adminConsoleEnglish - 12.2.1.4.0)
-> ERROR: found unresolved prerequisite DEP for GLCM Encryption 13.9.4.2.0 (glcm_common - 13.9.4.0.0)[UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED]
ERROR: couldn't select GLCM Encryption 13.9.4.2.0[TINFO|NOTINSTALLED|SELECTED] [null][UNRESOLVED|NOTINSTALLED|NOTSELECTED]
ERROR: couldn't select Administration Console Additional Language Help Files 12.2.1.4.0[TINFO|NOTINSTALLED|SELECTED] [null]

If the wizard is starting it might be creating a log file. If it isn't, or you can't find it, and nothing helpful is being reported on the command line then you will probably have to try to capture the wizard screen before it disappears, and hope that says something helpful. Searching for a log file is probably your best bet - unless this is a path or permission problem, and that also prevents a log being created.

@AlexPoole I added logs
